# Approach for Python wrapper around C++ Asynchronous Programming Model

Tags: python, c++, asynchronous, ctypes

I need to create a python wrapper around C++ code that is heavily modeled around [APM model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I was researching, but cannot find good approach how to model this in Python. Options that I could think of, are:

1. Use `concurrent.futures.Future`

   - it is from 3.4, but I would like this wrapper to be used with any Python version (2.x included), maybe use [this backported version](https://pythonhosted.org/futures/)
   - I don't like the fact that APM defines `timeout` in `Begin*` call, and `Future` define `timeout` in .result()
2. Create my own C++ library that will turn those async calls into sync calls

   - doesn't allow that way for user to do fancy async stuff in Python
   - braindead to implement
3. Use Twisted's `Deferred` or some similar library and emulate those Begin/End with it

   - I would not want to have dependencies on other libraries, if possible
4. Build my own Future/Deferred type

   - I would like to avoid that, so I can focus on app logic and just reuse stable/reliable stuff around
5. Something else I am missing

So, none of these is perfect and at this point, I am inclined to approach 2, but need to ask here am I missing something obvious? Also, does anybody knows any other wrapper that needed to do this and how they pulled it off?